# Kotlin Zip only every second element

Tags: kotlin

I have a `List` and I basically want to zip it, but only every second entry.

What I mean is: I want my List `[a,1,b,2]` to become `[(a,1),(b,2)]`, 
I currently use `zipWith`.
But it does not give me the expected result, it gives me `[(a,1),(1,b),(b,2)]`.

Am I being completely stupid right now, or is there no other solution than just ignore every second tuple? (e.g. by adding a `filter` afterwards) Is there no operator for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [chunked function](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#windowed-chunked-zipwithnext) in Kotlin 1.2 does exactly what you need:

```
val list = listOf("a", 1, "b", 2)
val newList = list.chunked(2)  // returns listOf(listOf("a", 1), listOf("b", 2))
```

Comment: that's it. Thanks! I actually ignored that function, because it doesn't  return Pairs. I wasn't aware of destructuring for Lists, though. :-)